# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. CS0029

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am having a problem with my code. I do not know how to fix this error so your help will be much appreciated.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Number, season;


            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value of a mounth of the year: (E.G. 1 for January, 2 for Febuary)");
            Number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (Number)
            {
                case 1: Console.WriteLine("January"); break;
                case 2: Console.WriteLine("Febuary"); break;
                case 3: Console.WriteLine("March"); break;
                case 4: Console.WriteLine("April"); break;
                case 5: Console.WriteLine("May"); break;
                case 6: Console.WriteLine("June"); break;
                case 7: Console.WriteLine("July"); break;
                case 8: Console.WriteLine("Augest"); break;
                case 9: Console.WriteLine("September"); break;
                case 10: Console.WriteLine("October"); break;
                case 11: Console.WriteLine("November"); break;
                case 12: Console.WriteLine("December"); break;
            }

            if (Number == 1)
            {
                season = "Winter";
            }
            else if (Number == 2)
            {
                season = "Winter";
            }
            else if (Number == 3)
            {
                season = "Spring";
            }
            else if (Number == 4)
            {
                season = "Spring";
            }
            else if (Number == 5)
            {
                season = "Spring";
            }
            else if (Number == 6)
            {
                season = "Summer";
            }
            else if (Number == 7)
            {
                season = "Summer";
            }
            else if (Number == 8)
            {
                season = "Summer";
            }
            else if (Number == 9)
            {
                season = "Autumn";
            }
            else if (Number == 10)
            {
                season = "Autumn";
            }
            else if (Number == 11)
            {
                season = "Autumn";
            }
            else if (Number == 12)
            {
                season = "Winter";
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valad value for a month (i.e. 1-12)");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The seaon is:\t" + season);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code i have written. On every part of the 'if' statement where the season is there is a CS0029 error. I have an understanding that it is because I'm using an int and it cant convert to a string. But if I'm wrong then please correct me. 
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: `int Number; string season;`

Comment: You defined `season` as int: `int Number, season;`. But you are assigning to it a string. declare it as `string season`

Comment: `int Number, season;` declares both `Number` & `season` as int: use `int Number; string season;` instead.

Comment: Ok thanks . I'm new to c# so i just didn't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: I have changed it but now I have an Error code CS0165. "Use of unassigned local variable 'season'."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int Number, season;
```

this is wrong because the number variable is type of integer but the  `season` variable can't be integer

You have to define Like this

```
int Number;    
string season = string.Empty;
```

Comment: I have changed it but now I have an Error code CS0165. "Use of unassigned local variable 'season'.". what does that mean?

Comment: dude if it is String you have to assign the value. 
please follow My code
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""string season= string.Empty;""""""""""""""

Comment: Thanks for the help.